# How to get User Email from User model in a function Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

Hi Iam newbie to Django,

I written an function to send email from any user who need to know more info about the trip.
I didn't know to how to collect posted user email id from user database. need help.

```
def PostDetailView(request, pk):
    context = {}
    context["data"] = Post.objects.get(id=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST['uName']
        # phone = request.POST["phone"]
        email = request.POST['uEmail']
        desc = request.POST['uDes']
        
        
        userEmail = I need to assign email id of this trip posted user
        
                
        subject = 'Iam Interested in your Trip'
        message = f'Hi Iam {name}, Iam Interested you trip. Please share more details on {email} {desc}'
        email_from = email
        recipient_list = [userEmail, ]
        send_mail( subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, desc )
        messages.success(request, 'Message Sent Successfully.')
        return render(request, 'ads/detail.html',context)
        

    return render(request, 'ads/detail.html',context)
```

Need help to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **posted user** is the current authenticated user ?

so you can get email:

```py
userEmail = request.user.email
```

Comment: This issue fixed when the user is authenticated is there other way to send. 'I got this error after logout 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'email'

Comment: How can you get email of user without login ?

Comment: Here is the scenario the user add trip and the people who visit the website need send email to the user. I don't know how to do that. need help, Is there way or better solution for this?

Comment: solution is to make mandatory for user to create account before add trip and ask for people to register too for sending email. Every trip website work like that